# BLE module RN4871 not able to connect with Matlab

Tags: matlab, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, microchip

I am using the RN4871 bluetooth module from microchip for sending sensor data to matlab. I programmed the module according to this website. [www.allaboutcircuits.com](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/how-to-build-analog-sensor-analog-output-microchip-rn487x-bluetooth-module/)
I was able to program the module through the serial monitor and also changed the name of the module to "RN4871_SAKIN".

Now I wanted to read the analog values from the characteristics UUID. For that I wanted to use matlab. I searched with the command "blelist" the available nearby BLE devices and found my device.
But when I try to connect to the device matlab gives me an error. I tried using ble("name") and ble("address") but both gave me the same error.

I dont think that matlab is the issue here. But I really dont know how to solve the problem. Going through the troubleshooting section in matlab was also not helpfull.
[Matlab Failed to connect to device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyByK.jpg)

Has someone experience connecting with this bluetooth module?

Cheers

Comment: Please do not post images of error messages. Have you tried to connect to your BLE device using a BLE scanner on your phone, like nRF Connect?

Comment: Yes I tried nRF Connect and my phone was able to make a connection.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Win10. I know that in the link the guy used linux but i would like to use matlab because i dont have any experience in python.

Comment: In the matlab troubleshooting section are some tipps about windows 10. They are not connection related, but maybe they work for you as well. For example try pairing the device with your notebook first: Windows Settings > Devices > Add Bluetooth or other device

Comment: So I saw something interesting. I used an other PC. I checked with what serial monitor displays during the communication fails through matlab. When I type the command ble("name") the serial monitor shows me that the values of the sensor is measured until the error message in matlab pops up.

Comment: I could not find the BLE module in the bluetooth manager.